# visualbasic cant delete .zip file in a directory

Tags: vb.net, delete-file

i have three folder  in "D:\TestField". These are "backups","ExampleFileUpdatePrimary","ExampleFileUpdateSecondary.zip". I can delete "D:\TestField\ExampleFileUpdatePrimary" folder ,but i cant delete "D:\TestField\ExampleFileUpdateSecondary.zip"

my sub function is ;

```
 Private Sub DeleteFolder(ByVal path As String)
        path = path.Remove(path.Length - 1) 'D:\TestField\ExampleFileUpdatePrimary
        Dim path2 = path & ".zip" 'D:\TestField\ExampleFileUpdateSecondary.zip
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(path, FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)  'its working

        'Dim di = New IO.DirectoryInfo(path2)  'try1
        'di.Delete(True)

        'IO.Directory.Delete(path2)    'try2

        'My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(path2, FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents) 'try3

    End Sub
```

try1,try2  exceptions says " The directory name is invalid"

try3 exception says "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: ''D:\TestField\ExampleFileUpdateSecondary.zip "

i couldnot find a new solution or  try to delete a .zip file in code

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directory entries ending on `.zip` are usually *files* not folders, even though Windows Explorer displays them as folders.

Since they are files, use [`File.Delete`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-5.0) instead.